# Setting primary key start value in Django model

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, primary-key

I am preparing a model as follows:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True, null=False, unique=True)
```

But my primary key must be a valid 9+ digit integer value. If I set the start index as `100000000`. then any value generated as `id` will be 9 digit or greater in length.

But django do not support this. How can I implement this with *minimum direct interference* to django?

I am using `Django 1.3` and `Postgresql 9.1`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not a django user but I think the postgresql command you are looking for is:

`ALTER SEQUENCE big_integer_seq RESTART 100000000;`

Best to read the documentation for django/postgresql.

Comment: +1, this is database-specific and not really Django's responsibility.