# id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) but start from 9999 how?

Tags: django

I want to define my own

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

in my model, but I want it to start from 9999, how can I do it?

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/21095825/3001761; I think you need to do this at the DB, rather than Django, level.

Answer (score 2):

Its not Django specific but DB specific. You can use [`ALTER SEQUENCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altersequence.html) to do that.

> `ALTER SEQUENCE` changes the parameters of an existing sequence
>   generator.

```
ALTER SEQUENCE my_seq RESTART with 9999;
```

The `RESTART` clause will change the current value of the sequence.